# Insert record newly inserted ID into child records SQL Server OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a ProjectStaging table from which I want to insert records into my Project table based on a no match on the StagingID field. The Project table has its own auto incrementing ProjectID. This part if fine (using NOT EXISTS).

Next I want to create three ProjectLineItems for each inserted project with the newly inserted ProjectID and also default settings of 1, 2 and 3 in the Status field. I am using OUTPUT to extract the ProjectID, saving the id to a TempTable and storing it in the variable @NewProjectID later on for inserting the 3 line items. But I am getting an error saying ProjectID is null. Why would that be? Is my OUTPUT id not making it to the TempTable?

---here's the SQL

```
DECLARE @NewProjectID int
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(id int) 

INSERT INTO Project
    (
    StagingID,
    Field1,
    Field2
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ProjectID INTO @TempTable(id)
    SELECT
    StagingID,
    Field1,
    Field2
    FROM ProjectStaging
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM ProjectStaging WHERE Project.StagingID = ProjectStaging.StagingID)

    SELECT @NewProjectID = id FROM @TempTable 

    INSERT INTO ProjectLineItems(ProjectID, Status) VALUES(@NewProjectID, 1)
    INSERT INTO ProjectLineItems(ProjectID, Status) VALUES(@NewProjectID, 2)
    INSERT INTO ProjectLineItems(ProjectID, Status) VALUES(@NewProjectID, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the OUTPUT inside the insert, have you tried:
`SELECT @NewProjectID = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ProjectStaging'))`

This will set `@NewProjectID` to the value of the last inserted identity value for ProjectID

Any reason why that wouldn't work for you?

So your new code would be:

```
DECLARE @NewProjectID int

INSERT INTO Project
    (
    StagingID,
    Field1,
    Field2
    )
    SELECT
    StagingID,
    Field1,
    Field2
    FROM ProjectStaging
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM ProjectStaging WHERE Project.StagingID = ProjectStaging.StagingID)

    SELECT @NewProjectID = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ProjectStaging'))

    INSERT INTO ProjectLineItems(ProjectID, Status) VALUES(@NewProjectID, 1)
    INSERT INTO ProjectLineItems(ProjectID, Status) VALUES(@NewProjectID, 2)
    INSERT INTO ProjectLineItems(ProjectID, Status) VALUES(@NewProjectID, 3)
```

Comment: I think the problem is he is not inserting anything but your way would not check for this.

Comment: Tom that doesn't work. In fact I tried that approach first with the OUTPUT statement, I cannot have a SET clause inside an INSERT statement. The only thing I can put inside that INSERT is a SELECT. This is why I went with the TempTable and variable approach.

Comment: @SKale Modified to use a select, this should work. You may need to add one to NewProjectID, since the select is part of the insert statement here it may have the previous value and not current value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something... You want to insert into Project where something exists in staging but does not exist in Project right?

Then you want your statement to look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Project
    (
    StagingID,
    Field1,
    Field2
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ProjectID INTO @TempTable(id)
    SELECT
    StagingID,
    Field1,
    Field2
    FROM ProjectStaging
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ProjectStaging Stage
    JOIN Project Proj ON Stage.StagingID = Proj.StagingID)
```

also your table can have more than one row, if it does

```
 SELECT @NewProjectID = id FROM @TempTable
```

will give an error

---

To use the table do this:

```
INSERT INTO ProjectLineItems(ProjectID, Status)
  SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM @TempTable
```

Comment: My insert into the Project table is working fine. I don't think that is a problem although I will try your suggestion of using the JOIN keyword. I also do acknowledge the problem of multiple records the TempTable but there's no way around using a table because I cannot directly insert the ID into the children. So my problem still remains: how do I get the OUTPUT of the inserted ID and insert it into the children records?

Comment: @Skale - See my edit on how to do the insert using a table.

Comment: I just retested and my original code actually works. but it is inserting only the last ID inserted. Am I going to have to use a cursor to do this? I have not tried your suggestion with ROWNUMBER yet. honestly I don't understand how that code works.